# Lucene search where a field MUST start with certain letters

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm trying to search for results within a range e.g. A TO C. However the results are coming in with results that contain letters within the range but I only want results that START with letters within the range.

Comment: The query syntax for RangeQuery is [A TO C]. In this particular case you should receive all results starting with A, B and terms containing only one letter C.

Alternatively you could try A* OR B* OR C* query

Comment: @Akeem: please don't change the whole question, invalidating the existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Comment: Yeah I should have added a comment to clarify that I edited the question to clarify. Apologies

Comment: could you include sample output? I'd recommend building query object in your code, not in Lucene parser to be sure that the error is not in the parser code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using frange provided by the QParser plugin available for solr 1.4

```
{!frange l=A u=C}fieldname
```

I got the info from [here](http://yonik.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/ranges-over-functions-in-solr-1-4/)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way -- During index time, create another field that contains only the first letter.  So if the field currently contains:

```
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
```

then index this in a separate field (non-analyzed):

```
A
B
C
```

Then use range query as usual

```
myFieldFirstLetter:[A TO C]
```